# Is it possible to have the Cloud shell and the VM within the same VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-networking

I want to have the google Cloud Shell and the VM within the same VPC, so that I can access the windows VM via its internal IP address. I setup a Serveless VPC access connector so that I can access the VM via cloud shell. But I am unable to ping the VM via its internal IP address, which implies that it is not in the same VPC.

Does anyone know if its possible to ping the VM from cloud shell using its internal IP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot use Cloud Shell to access or ping internal IP address from VM instance for the reason that it is on a separate network. You can check this by running this command `ip -4 addr` in your cloud shell.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Shell instances are not located within your VPC. They're managed by Google and isolated from your cloud resources because Cloud Shell doesnt reside inside your VPC.
Using VPC Peering could be a way to do it.
Serverless VPC Access Connector could potentially deal with it but its was not designed for this.
The remaining solutions would be to create a Bastion Host, a VM that sits within your VPC and is exposed to the internet securely as a jump server.
You can also create an SSH connection through IAP, which does not require the VM to have an external IP address.